# CentOS running out of space for website files

Tags: centos, web-hosting, disk-space-utilization

Disclaimer: I know my way around Linux, but I'm out of the loop for a while.

I have a CentOS 7 server where I host a couple of my small websites in `/var/www/website1`, `/var/www/website2` and so on. Now I want to add one more website which will have big files. I started uploading stuff and got a "out of disk space" message. When I run `df -h` I get below output:

```
[root@ns304241 kosa]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        20G   19G  4.7M 100% /
devtmpfs        7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7.8G  885M  7.0G  12% /run
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md3        1.8T   48G  1.7T   3% /home
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Notice that my `/home` directory is 1.8T while `/var/www` is, I assume on `/dev/root` device, which is only 20G.
I was under an impression that websites should be hosted in `/var/www` for the simple reason of having multiple users access to the website files and peace of mind with permissions against hosting websites in `/home`.

1. Is my system set up in some weird way? Shouldn't `/var` be on the big (1.8T) drive, as all the logs are there and can easily take up a lot of space?
2. Should I move my websites to `/home`?
3. But what if I need two different users to access the same website files?
4. What's the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [symlinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#POSIX_and_Unix-like_operating_systems) your websites from a directory on the larger drive. That's what I do since all my actual site data is on a drive that gets backed up.

```
ln -s /actual/path/to/file /var/www/website3
```

Comment: with the symlink done, should the `root` directive in nginx still point to `/var/www/site1` or `/home/user/site1` ?

Comment: If you want to keep everything pointed at the /var/www for your config then you can leave it pointed there. With the symbolic link setup the directories can be referenced as normal.

Comment: just got it working with a symlink, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a company setup I would set this server up again, I would make it so that /var indeed has all the storage. You can do that on the setup. Is this just one big drive? If its multiple I'd use lvm setup.

Comment: It's a dedicated server with a preconfigured system. I don't think I have an option to repartition it.